# How to style one column of ion-grid?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, grid

I have three columns in ion-row in which middle column is of size 4 while 1st and third one are of size 3. The problem is that the padding and width of middle column is adding a gap between first and last icon. I want them to stick together with a very little gap (10-12px approx). I changed max-width of middle column to fit-content in inspect style and it worked. But I'm unable to style it in scss.

**HTML**

```
  <ion-row class="bottom-section ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center">
    <ion-col size="3" class="col ion-text-end">
      <ion-button class="delete-btn" color="light" size="large">
        <ion-icon class="delete-icon"  slot="icon-only" size="large" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4" class="col col-2 ion-text-center" width-100>
      <ion-button class="record-btn" color="danger" size="large">
        <ion-icon class="record-icon"  slot="icon-only" size="large" name="mic"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="3" class="col ion-text-start">
      <ion-button class="add-btn" color="light" size="large">
        <ion-icon class="add-icon"  slot="icon-only" size="large" name="add"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

**SCSS**

```
.col {
    border: 1px solid;
}

.col-2 {
    --max-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

**Default Style**
[image: This is default image]

**Required Style**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `ion-grid` is a good solution here when you need more fine tune control over a small number of items. Try something like this instead.

```html
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <div class="single-button">
      <ion-button color="light" class="delete-btn">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-label>Delete</ion-label>
    </div>
    <div class="single-button">
      <ion-button color="danger" class="record-btn">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="mic"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-label>Record</ion-label>
    </div>
    <div class="single-button">
      <ion-button color="light" class="add-btn">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-label>Add</ion-label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.buttons-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .single-button {
        text-align: center;

        .delete-btn,
        .add-btn {
            margin: 0px 5px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            --border-radius: 50%;
            display: block;
        }

        .record-btn {
            margin: 0px 5px;
            height: 70px;
            width: 70px;
            --border-radius: 50%;
            display: block;

            ion-icon {
                font-size: 32px;
            }
        }
        ion-label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried with div and the gaps were removed. But i also wanna write labels below each button. I thought that with grid it would be easier. How to achieve that with div ?

Comment: Updated the answer to show how you could do that. `<ion-grid>` is great for table-like layouts or for fluid content when fine control isn't needed. If you want to do something more custom then you're better off just writing custom CSS

Comment: Yes thanks for information. The labels are shown but they are not on the same level. How to bring those labels on a same level like ion-row ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "same level" or why that matters? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As record button is bigger than other two buttons, record label is vertically below the other two labels. Can you bring those other two labels on the level of record label? Thanks anyways.

Comment: Haha ok you're moving the goalposts. I answered without knowing your full requirements. Adjust the top margin for the first and last label to even them out.